# Python - Rolling two dice with different numbers of sides

Tags: python, histogram, dice

I've already written the code for a program that takes the number of sides from the user and rolls two of those dice 1000 times and shows the sums on a histogram.

How do I do the same thing but the user can choose different dice, for example a 6 sided and an 8 sided one?

This is my code for the similar dice:

```
from random import randint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import defaultdict

#Asking for the sides
n = int(input("How many sides? 6, 8 or 10?\n"))
number = 1000 #How many times it's rolled

#Making empty dictionaries for each type of die
sums6 = defaultdict(int)
sums8 = defaultdict(int)
sums10 = defaultdict(int)

#Making conditions for each type and plotting the histograms
if n == 6:
    for _ in range(number):
        die1 = randint(1,6)
        die2 = randint(1,6)
        sums6[die1 + die2] += 1
    plt.bar(list(sums6.keys()), sums6.values(), color='b')
    plt.xlabel('Result')
    plt.ylabel('Frequency of Result')
    plt.grid(axis='y', alpha=0.5)
    plt.show()
if n == 8:
    for _ in range(number):
        die1 = randint(1,8)
        die2 = randint(1,8)
        sums8[die1 + die2] += 1
    plt.bar(list(sums8.keys()), sums8.values(), color='g')
    plt.xlabel('Result')
    plt.ylabel('Frequency of Result')
    plt.grid(axis='y', alpha=0.5)
    plt.show()
if n == 10:
    for _ in range(number):
        die1 = randint(1,10)
        die2 = randint(1,10)
        sums10[die1 + die2] += 1
    plt.bar(list(sums10.keys()), sums10.values(), color='r')
    plt.xlabel('Result')
    plt.ylabel('Frequency of Result')
    plt.grid(axis='y', alpha=0.5)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: I would suggest you to create an object called dice, in which you could indicate the number of faces on the dice. Thereafter, I would also add a method called randValue or similar, which would return a random integer within the range [1-faces]. Additionally, I would also consider just a general case in your main function, in which you could specify the two dices (regardless it’s features). Hope this help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want user to be able to input multiple sides in a dice you could just take 2 variables as input and generate random numbers from them, also no need to add conditions, you can just specify the selected number of sides in dice in the randint itself

```
from random import randint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import defaultdict

#Asking for the sides
n = int(input("How many sides Dice1? 6, 8 or 10?\n"))
m = int(input("How many sides Dice2? 6, 8 or 10?\n"))
number = 1000 #How many times it's rolled

#Making empty dictionaries for each type of die
sums = defaultdict(int)

#Making conditions for each type and plotting the histograms

for _ in range(number):
    die1 = randint(1,n)
    die2 = randint(1,m)
    sums[die1 + die2] += 1
plt.bar(list(sums.keys()), sums.values(), color='b')
plt.xlabel('Result')
plt.ylabel('Frequency of Result')
plt.grid(axis='y', alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import randint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import defaultdict

#Asking for the sides
n1, n2 = map(int, input("Enter a two values: ").split())

number = 1000 #How many times it's rolled

#Making empty dictionaries for each type of die
sums = defaultdict(int)


#Making conditions for each type and plotting the histograms
for _ in range(number):
    die1 = randint(1,n1)
    die2 = randint(1,n2)
    sums[die1 + die2] += 1
plt.bar(list(sums.keys()), sums.values(), color='b')
plt.xlabel('Result')
plt.ylabel('Frequency of Result')
plt.grid(axis='y', alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ask the user to provide comma-separated numbers of sides, then make the program work for any number of dice with any number of sides:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
from random import randint

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


NUMBER = 1000  # How many times it's rolled


# Asking for the sides
dice = input("What dice to use? (comma-separated, e.g. 6,8,10): ")
try:
    dice = [int(item) for item in dice.split(",")]
except ValueError:
    print("Error: input", dice, "is not comma-separated integers.")
    exit(1)

sums = defaultdict(int)

for _ in range(NUMBER):
    roll_result = [randint(1, m) for m in dice]
    sums[sum(roll_result)] += 1
plt.bar(list(sums.keys()), sums.values(), color='b')
plt.xlabel('Result')
plt.ylabel('Frequency of Result')
plt.grid(axis='y', alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

Example:

```
$ python dice.py
What dice to use? (comma-separated, e.g. 6,8,10): 8,8,10,24
<displays a plot>
```